# POS-Tagging API for Italian Language on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, ruby, nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I need help Looking for POS-Tagging API that works on documents in Italian.
My preference is for open source code (possibly; ruby, jruby, macruby, java, scala).
The program that I write will run on Mac OsX and I have already explored [this list](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html#Taggers) but there is no much for "Italian Language"

[As of 10.8, Cocoa NSLinguisticTagger provides parts-of-speech tags and lemmas for Spanish and Italian](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html), I could try it, but before upgrading my OSX 10.7 please let me know if you think really worth it or if I have other good options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tree Tagger](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/) comes with support for Italian and runs on OS X.